# Switching between two parts of a circuit using basic components

Tags: switches, relay, basic

I'm designing a circuit in which i need to temporarily switch between different branches of it. I know that it can be done using a relay with coil etc, but I'm wondering if there is a way to do it some other way?

I know that there was similar topic, but unfortunately it was not well answered.

Basically i want to do something like this, but instead of a relay I wanna use some basic components:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fputVr.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Anyone got an idea?

Comment: How do you want to control the switch? Is it correct the load current will be about 10 mA? Are the loads actually resistive or are they inductive (like motors)? Is the source voltage actually 1 V or is it higher?

Comment: They are resistive. Currents will be no more than 50mA tops.

Comment: Okay. And what's going to control the switches? Do you have other supplies available besides the 1 V?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use nmos and pmos.  Add a pullup or pulldown to turn one or the other on during microcontroller config.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTAWl2.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Look at a family of devices called transistors. Ofcourse, what type of transistor is appropriate can only be decided once you give more requirements - how quickly are you going to have to switch between the two? What currents and voltages? How are you going to drive the circuit?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYuXPU.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Yeah, the thing is that I'm short of pins on my microcontroller. I was just wondering if this could be done using only one input:)

Answer (score 0):

Implement the circuit using transistors as Joren suggested, but combine inputs A and B onto one pin with an inverter such that A is selected with the pin is high and B is selected with the pin is low. You could use a standard logic inverter or you could create an inverter with one more transistor.